# Smoothing a fitted function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Good afternoon everybody,

I have been trying to smoothen out a fitted function I have as an output of an exponential fitting process. The lines of code I am using look like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = (0.005, 0.025, 0.05, 0.075, 0.1)
y = (1.0, 0.7261356155365372, 0.5170068027210885, 0.3651525126179504, 0.26135615536537193)
plt.plot(x, y, "r")
x = np.array(x, dtype=float)
y = np.array(y, dtype=float)
def func(x, a, b):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
print(popt[0], popt[1])

plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), "b")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[My graphical output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9QbV.png)

The output is mathematically satisfactory, and my fitted values `print(popt[0], popt[1])` are perfectly reasonable. The main issue is that the blue line (fitted function) **is not smooth**. I have been googling about function smoothening, but I found nothing which applies to fitted functions, and the ones acting on my original datasets, such as numpy's `np.linspace()`, are not helping out.

Many thanks to anybody that can help me out with this task!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the function is definitely smooth, since it's a nice exponential. The problem is that you are plotting it on a very coarse grid `x`. Of course, you want to keep `x` fixed when fitting the curve, since those values of `x` correspond to your known observations `y`. But we can use a different domain when plotting, as follows.

Replace the lines starting with `plt.plot` with:

```py
new_x = np.linspace(0, 0.1) # or whatever domain you like
plt.plot(new_x, func(new_x, *popt), "b")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

And you should be good.

Comment: nice explanation

Comment: I think it should be `plt.plot(new_x, func(new_x, *popt), "b")`, shouldn`t it?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I had a typo! Forgot to put `new_x` as the argument to `func` -- I've edited my answer to reflect that

Comment: Works wonders Charlie Windolf! Thanks to @Flob as well for pointing the typo out, I was about to comment on that because I was getting a strange error.

Comment: @CharlieWindolf noticed it himself even before i finished typing my comment, so all praise goes to him ;)